# Howto preg_replace a specific char within parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got a bunch of strings like this one:

```
test; test2 (2;5%).
```

What I want to do with PHP now is to correct the ";" in the parentheses so it will look like:

```
test; test2 (2,5%) - mention the ",".
```

Code that I tried:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\(.;.\)/", ",", $string);
```

My eyes actually bleed from googling so please help me out with that :)

Answer (score 6):

1) Needed to escape the parenthesis with a backslash (`\`)

2) Didn't include the percent sign in your expression

3) Would have been replacing the entire bracketed expression (brackets included) with a single `,`

4) As Zimzat points out in the comments, it might be a better idea to replace the periods (`.`) with `\d+`, which matches numbers instead of any character.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\((\d+);(\d+%)\)/", "($1,$2)", $string);
```

Comment: What about making the . a [^)]? What about a + to say more than one number?

Comment: Yes, but I'd recommending using the following so that it matches numbers of any length instead of just a single number: `preg_replace("/\(([1-9]{1}[0-9]*),([0-9]*[1-9]{1})%\)/", "($1,$2)", $string);`  This will also make sure that the number has no leading or trailing 0s.

Comment: @GigaWatt: Does not the `+` modifier get that? I mean, `+` means 1 or more

Comment: Yup, the `+` modifier works, but when you use `+` for example, there's many more possible ways that a given number could be matched.  For example, using `+`, the number "123045" could be matched as ("123" and "045", "12" and "3045", etc).  If you had a really long decimal section and you were processing a lot of lines, it could start to weigh things down.

Comment: @GigaWatt I see your point, but how can you avoid that by writing `*` instead of `+`. By the way, I think `0,9%` is also a valid decimal number ;)

Comment: @elitalon: Oh balls.  This is why I hate being a perfectionist.

Comment: @GigaWatt: I doubt it's necessary in this case, but if performance were really an issue you could use possessive quantifiers: `/\((\d++);(\d++%)\)/`.  In any case, those `{1}` quantifiers do nothing but clutter up your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the characters next to the `;`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\((\d+);(\d+%)\)/', "($1,$2)", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

to replace multiple occurences of eg comma in () i will use this code

```
  $text = preg_replace_callback("/\{((.*),(.*))\}/sim", function($matches){
    return str_replace(',', ':comma:', $matches[0]);
  }, $text);
```